# RDLC report Formatting issue in C#

Tags: c#, formatting, export-to-excel, rdlc

I am trying hard to format the RDLC report in C#. I have created excel like look which has columns and rows, but when i export it into an excel , some column and/ or row lines disappear.
Is there any other formatting parameter, I am missing or It's a bug?
Does anyone has faced this problem before?

Note: I have used BorderStyle : Solid to all the text-boxes in Matrix/Table.
Please help.
Source:
[image]
Result after Export to excel:
[image]

Here 3 vertical lines are missing.

Comment: What i have encountered when exporting to excel from rdlc is that columns that are furthest to the right and that contain no data for the entire column fall away. Do not know why they made it do that

Comment: You have no visibilty set on any of your rows conditionally?

Comment: Hi, Hano. I haven't used "dynamic visibility" to rows. Some rows are static and some are dynamic and all rows are visible. But the vertical line disappears somewhere in excel sheet.

Comment: One thing that was also weird which i encountered with reports generated from rdlc but this was with word export tables, is the borders disappearing on the user interface of word. only if you zoom in will you see the lines are actually there, possibly check if its the same in your case. All you borders are set to 1pt on all sides and solid line black?

Comment: Yes, I have checked all the border Style = "Solid" and all borders are set to "1 pt".

Comment: I'll have to take a look then at the report file itself to be of further help